# How can I use intercept-method using its filters, not namespace?

Tags: spring, spring-security, intercept

I'm trying to add some intercept-method in my application (using spring security) without namespaces.
So here is what I did:
First, I added a filter to filter-chain-map named "methodSecurityInterceptor" as you can see:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="
        ConcurrentSessionFilter,
        securityContextPersistenceFilter,
        sessionManagementFilter,
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor,
        methodSecurityInterceptor,
        logoutFilter" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Then I introduced its bean like this:

```
<bean id="methodSecurityInterceptor"
class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="MyMethodMetdataSource">

    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="MyMethodMetdataSource" class="com.datx.dao.MyMethodMetdataSource">
</bean>
```

And I have my MyMethodMetadataSource implemented like this:

```
public class MyMethodMetdataSource extends AbstractMethodSecurityMetadataSource{

@Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Method arg0, Class<?> arg1) {

    String url = arg0.getName();
    List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();

    attributes = getAttributesByURL2(url); //Here is my function which
                                           //returns corresponding roles

    return attributes;
}
    @Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Apparently I am not allowed to use ***methodSecurityInterceptor*** as it's not a filter!
So what should I do?
I've read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#aop-alliance) but I have no idea how to *use it with one of Spring AOP's proxying mechanisms*!
So... Any idea?

Comment: This looks very similar to the content of the answer I thought I gave you yesterday. Did you delete your previous question? I also gave you a pointer to an example in the Spring Security codebase, which uses AOP. Did you try to use that? Method security has nothing to do with web filters.

Comment: Yes, and thank you for that. I've read your answer and I thought the question should be asked this way. BTW, I did not understand how to use AOP. It's a bit fuzzy. Can you just give me a very simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example I gave you before,](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/intercept/method/aopalliance/MethodSecurityInterceptorWithAopConfigTests.java) is pretty much as simple as you can make it without using the namespace `<global-method-security>` element.

Use Spring's [AOP namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-schema) with a pointcut matching the method(s) you want to protect:

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id='targetMethods' expression='execution(* org.springframework.security.TargetObject.*(..))'/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref='securityInterceptor' pointcut-ref='targetMethods' />
</aop:config>
```

and declare the security interceptor as a bean:

```
<bean id='target' class='org.springframework.security.TargetObject'/>
<bean id='securityInterceptor' class='org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor' autowire='byType' >
   <property name='securityMetadataSource' ref="yourSecurityMetadataSource"/>
</bean>
```

External calls to that bean will then be routed through the security interceptor before the method is invoked.

I'd suggest you checkout the source and try running the test in a debugger to get a feel for how it works if you haven't use AOP before.

Comment: Thank you Luke, your suggestions were good and helped me a lot. Fortunately, I found the solution I was looking for, and I write it here for others.

Comment: This answer is right, pretty much as mine. I've wrote my answer to this question using proxies. see that too, if you are interested.

Comment: BTW, I did not understand where I should declare the class of mine to be secured! Can you explain it to me? Consider my class' name is ***myPackage.Manager2***

Comment: That is what the pointcut does. It's an AspectJ-style expression defining which methods should be secured.

Comment: So, how can I declare just one class to be secured? I see nowhere that a class is declared to be secured. Does your suggested code secure all classes?

Comment: There is a bean called `targetObject` declared, and the pointcut specifies all methods on that object. Please read the Spring documentation link I posted if you want more information, and the docs it refers to on declaring pointcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I found the answer to this question. 
One cannot use filters for intercept-method. So I suggest using proxies instead.
So here is the solution:
Change back the filter chain to its normal:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
<security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
        filters="
    ConcurrentSessionFilter,
    securityContextPersistenceFilter,
    sessionManagementFilter,
    authenticationProcessingFilter,
    exceptionTranslationFilter,
    filterSecurityInterceptor,
    logoutFilter" />
</security:filter-chain-map>
```

See what I did there? I removed the methodSecurityInterceptor.

Then add a proxy:

```
<bean id="autoProxyCreator" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>methodSecurityInterceptor</value> <!-- Responsible for checking roles and accesspaths -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="beanNames">
        <list>
            <value>Manager2</value> <!--The Class that I want to protect its methods -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Of course we have to add these beans to application context too:

```
<bean id="methodSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="MyMethodMetdataSource">            
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="MyMethodMetdataSource" class="com.datx.dao.MyMethodMetdataSource">
</bean>
```

Here we go :)
Now every method in Manager2.java will be checked for every method call.